# Want to save content from a textarea server sided (in a file on the server permanent)

Tags: php, file, server, uploading

How's it going?
I'm relatively new to the php scene so I don't know everything. My latest project is a **file-/imageviewer**. I've already got the basic script to give out the Files, Images and you can open them also. Yesterday I programmed an area for editing this textfiles (such as .md, .txt, .pdf,..). But I haven't seen a solution to save the content on the files permanent (server sided). With **`file_put_contents()`** and **`fputs()`** the content only gets saved client sided so every time I refresh the page the "new" content is away. Does anyone has an idea to fix this or thinks he knows how to do it a different way? The most important thing is, that you can edit the .pdf files, the other files were only supposed to be an extra feature.
Here's the site I'm working on (I'm a german, don't wonder ...^^):

http://florian.thomasgoetzrath.de/pdfviewer/viewer.php

Thanks to all fast and constructive helpers :^),
F9lke

Comment: The simplest way is, to replace existing file with edited one on server side.

Comment: How come writing to file has to do with client or server? May be client is not displaying content written in file in your case?